# case sensitive sql search in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, case-sensitive

So I've been using the query builder in visual studio (visual basic) to search a local mdb file. I have a button that is clicked to make a prompt for a search, and it works fine except that is is not case sensitive. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, FullTime, HireDate, Salary
FROM SalesStaff
WHERE LastName like ? + '%'
```

My professor wants us to use the `InStr` fuction, but how do I get that to work with a prompt?

(`InputBox` in my vb form code). Furthermore, it doesn't seem to have case sensitivity either. This is the first time I am using SQL, so I hardly know what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The default MS SQL installation is not case sensitive.  Here is how to temporarily or permanently change it.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/

Comment: It told me ALTER TABLE is not supported...

Comment: ALTER TABLE is part of the core SQL standard....are you sure it didn't tell you that you don't have rights to the table?

Comment: I'd likely ask the professor why on earth he wants to use the InStr function? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can amend the collation settings of your database/table.
Alternatively if you just want a case sensitive comparison on this one statement you can use the `collate` keyword, such as below:

```
select 1 where 'abc' = 'ABC'
select 1 where 'abc' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'ABC' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
select 1 where 'abc' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = 'ABC' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
select 1 where upper('abc') collate Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'ABC' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
select 1 where upper('abc') collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = 'ABC' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

CI stands for case insensitive.

CS stands for case sensitive.